# Comparing char to Int in c++

Tags: c++, types, casting, char, int

in c++, is it okay to compare an int to a char because of implicit type casting? Or am I misunderstanding the concept?

For example,  can I do

```
int x = 68;
char y;
std::cin >> y;
//Assuming that the user inputs 'Z';
if(x < y) 
{
 cout << "Your input is larger than x";
}
```

Or do we need to first convert it to an int?

so

```
 if(x < static_cast<int>(y)) 
{
 cout << "Your input is larger than x";
}
```

Comment: Beware that it is permissible that `sizeof(int) == 1` and that `char` is unsigned, in which case both sides get converted to `unsigned int`. That's unusual, though.

Comment: Please avoid magic numbers, write what you mean:  Not 68 but `'D'`. Also, even if `sizeof(int)>1`, beware of implementation defined signedness of `char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can compare an `int` to some `char`, like you can compare an `int` to some `short`, but it might be considered bad style. I would code

```
if (x < (int)y)
```

or like you did

```
if (x < static_cast<int>(y))
```

which I find a bit too verbose for that case....

BTW, if you intend to use bytes not as `char` consider also the `int8_t` type (etc...) from `<cstdint>`

Don't forget that on some systems, `char` are `signed` by default, on others they are `unsigned` (and you could explicit `unsigned char` vs `signed char`).

Comment: Never knew that to be bad style. Just that generally comparing different type values is error-prone.

Comment: Gratuitous casts (especially C-style ones) are often considered bad style.

Comment: @Alan: Hm, my comment was in line with you, while i posted. Later edits to the answer though changed that. Damn.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with **both** versions is that you cannot be sure about the value that results from negative/large values (the values that are negative if `char` is indeed a `signed char`). This is implementation defined, because the implementation defines whether `char` means `signed char` or `unsigned char`.

The only way to fix this problem is to cast to the appropriate signed/unsigned *char* type first:

```
if(x < (signed char)y)
```

or

```
if(x < (unsigned char)y)
```

Omitting this cast will result in implementation defined behavior.

Personally, I generally prefer use of `uint8_t` and `int8_t` when using chars as numbers, precisely because of this issue.

---

This still assumes that the value of the `(un)signed char` is within the range of possible `int` values on your platform. This may not be the case if `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int) == 1` (possible only if a `char` is 16 bit!), and you are comparing signed and unsigned values.

To avoid this problem, ensure that you use either

```
signed x = ...;
if(x < (signed char)y)
```

or

```
unsigned x = ...;
if(x < (unsigned char)y)
```

Your compiler will hopefully complain with warning about mixed signed comparison if you fail to do so.

Comment: it also assumes: [`PRECISION(UCHAR_MAX) < PRECISION(INT_MAX)`](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2952) (likely in practice)

Comment: @jfs Right, forgot about that corner case. I've added a note on this to the answer now. Hope you like it.

Answer (score 3):

Your code will compile and *work*, for some definition of work.

Still you might get unexpected results, because `y` is a `char`, which means its signedness is implementation defined. That combined with unknown size of int will lead to much joy.

Also, please write the char literals you want, don't look at the ASCII table yourself. Any reader (you in 5 minutes) will be thankful.

Last point: Avoid gratuituous cast, they don't make anything better and may hide problems your compiler would normally warn about.

Answer (score 1):

The code you suggest will compile, but I strongly recommend the `static_cast` version. Using `static_cast` you will help the reader understand what do you compare to an integer.