# How to do == with a string and an int variable in c++

Tags: c++

I can't figure out how to check if an integer (x) is found inside a string (num). The if (num[i] == x) doesn't work. Can somebody please help me? Also I'm new to coding/ c++ and barely know the basics, so an easy-to-understand answer would be appreciated! Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int n, x;
  cin >> n >> x;
  string num;
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    num.append(to_string(i));
  }
  for (int i = 0; i <= num.size(); i++) {
    if (num[i] == x) {
      count += 1;
    }
  }
  cout << num;
  cout << count;
}
```

I tried converting it to a string, making a new string, and converting it to a char (not sure how this stuff works), but it keeps giving me the same error or it just doesn't run the way I was expecting. The count doesn't go up, and stays at zero.

Comment: This bit, `num[i] == x`, is comparing the ASCII value of the character in `num` to the integer `x`. I doubt that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [compare `char` and `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883451/comparing-char-to-int-in-c)

Comment: You should think of `==` as _testing for equality_.  It does not mean "is found inside".

Comment: `1234567891011121314151617181920` -- If this is the string, and you are searching for `12`, what is the expected output?  Is it `2`?

Comment: What is the topic of the chapter for your C++ textbook that this practice problem is from? Practice problems like that are designed to excersize one of several techniques or fundamental C++ principles, and you are expected to use them as part of solving this coding problem. If you can clarify what is the subject of this practice problem's chapter it will be helpful in pointing you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Convert `x` to a `string` and then use the [`string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) method to search for it in `num`, eg

```
auto index = num.find(to_string(x));
if (index != string::npos) {
    // found
} else {
    // not found
}
```